# How can I find a coordinate in a list inside of a dictionary for python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop, tkinter

I have a code using canvas in tkinter, and I've created lines with coordinates. I want to check through my dictionary of lines to figure out which has been clicked and subtract it from the list. My code goes something like this:

```
Dict = {list1 = (coordinates x1, y1, x2, y2)}
```

I want to get coordinates x1 and remove it from the list, and need help. Please any advice?

Comment: Please share some actual code - what you shared isn't Python, nor is it clear what it's supposed to do.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your dictionary is the following:

```
dict = {
    'list1': (x1, y1, x2, y2)
}
```

You can remove `x1` from the tuple like this:

```
dict = {
    'list1': (x1, y1, x2, y2)
}

list1 = list(dict['list1'])
list1.remove(x1)
dict['list1'] = tuple(list1)
print(dict['list1']) # returns (y1, x2, y2)
```